# Regex Not Capturing input

Tags: regex

I need to match over the alphabet {a,b} (meaning that we can discard any other letter since only `a` and `b` will exist):

1. All strings containing 2 or more `a`s.
2. All strings that do not contain the substring `bbb`.

Why is this RegEx:

```
((b{0,2}aaa*)+)|((aaa*b{0,2})+)
```

Not capturing `aab`?

Comment: because `aa` got captured by your first pattern.

Comment: And the second alternative requires 2 `a` at least.

Comment: Because it's matching the first part of the alternation on zero b's followed by two a's followed by zero a's.  Perhaps with more context of what you're trying to match, we can help with alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirements:

> All strings containing 2 or more a's. 
>   All strings that do not contain the substring bbb.

seem to argue for a simpler, lookahead based approach, instead of the trickier consuming pattern (depends on your exact workflow):

```
(?=a.*a)(?!.*bbb).*
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cE9pV4/4)

edit: to exclude all letters *except* a and b:

```
^(?=.*a.*a)(?!.*bbb)[ab]+$
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cE9pV4/6)

Comment: axxxxa would match too though

Comment: i thought "only a and b will exist" ?

Answer (score 1):

Because `aa` got captured by your first pattern. To get the desired output, you need to change the pattern order.

```
((aaa*b{0,2})+)|((b{0,2}aaa*)+)
```

Note that regex engine always try to match the input against the pattern which resides on the left side then it goes further to the right side. So it would be like,

```
1st|2nd|3rd
```

Update:

```
^(?!.*?bbb).*a.*a.*
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/wF8xJ6/1)

Comment: thanks. I edited the question as I forgot to add what I was looking for.

Comment: but that can be any letter not just a or b

Comment: what do you mean? pls explain it in your question with valid and invalid examples.

Comment: added to the question

Comment: add valid and invalid examples.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work too:

```
(ab{0,2}a)(ab{0,2})*
```